# ReactJS Conditional rendering is not working

Tags: reactjs

I have an input and whenever a user clicks in the box I want to see if the input is greater than 1

```
  updateQuery(e) {
   this.setState({ query: e.target.value });

   const optionValue = e.target.value.length;

  }
```

Then I want to do the following in render / return:

```
render() {
const { query } = this.state;

return (
  <div>
    {optionValue > 1 ? (
      <div className="loading">
        ) : (
      <div className="not-loading">
    )}
      <NewSearch query={query} updateQuery={this.updateQuery} />
    </div>
    <Debounce ms={1000}>
      <BusInfo query={query} />
    </Debounce>
  </div>
);
 }
```

But I get this issue:

Line 48:6:  Parsing error: Unexpected token ;

and my app won't run.

What am I missing here?

I've read this doc:

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Help!

Comment: I guess other than the points mentioned in the answers by others, you can simply just do this because all you want to do is change the className conditionally so:<div className={optionValue > 1 ? "loading" : "not-loading" > ... </div>

Comment: Apart from the first error, you will get an error for `optionValue` too, as it can't be accessed on your `render`. This value, should also be a part of your state. Check my answer below, where I analyze both of these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the only thing you need to change based a certain value of `optionValue` is the `className` of the div.

Hence, you can do something like this:

```js
return (
  <div>
    <div className={optionValue > 1 ? 'loading' : 'not-loading'}>
      <NewSearch query={query} updateQuery={this.updateQuery} />
    </div>
    <Debounce ms={1000}>
      <BusInfo query={query} />
    </Debounce>
  </div>
);
```

Also, `optionValue` is a const of `updateQuery` and cannot be accessed later on your `render`. You should also add `optionValue` on your state:

```js
updateQuery(e) {
   this.setState({ 
     query: e.target.value,
     optionValue: e.target.value.length
   });
}
```

And later on your render:

```js
const { query, optionValue } = this.state;
```

or just check on your render `query.length` instead of holding a new value just for this on your state.

---

In case you have classes that you want to share on both cases, you could use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to achieve this:

```js
<div className={`myClass1 myClass2 ${optionValue > 1 ? 'loading' : 'not-loading'}`}>
```

Comment: Michalis, thank you this is perfect, I have one more question tho. So the className with the condition. I need to add some other classes in but not in the conditional just normal css classed like <div className="more-classes" Need Conditional here>Content</div> - How does one do that? Thank you :)

Comment: Updated my answer for this last part :)

Comment: Thank you kind sir, this is perfect and actually, from your code snippets, I've just solidified my react knowledge so massive thank you, conditionals are a little clearer to me now.  Sometimes, I find the react docs a little confusing! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't define html tag like react component

Change this

```
   {optionValue > 1 ? (
      <div className="loading">True condition</div>
        ) : (
      <div className="not-loading">False condition</div>
    )}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your opening and closing tags don't match up, you have an unmatched closing `</div>`
2. If the conditionally rendered divs don't have any content, that's fine but they do need to be self-closing: `<div className="loading" />` (note the closing `/>`)

This should now work fine (although you may need to do `this.optionValue`)

```
updateQuery(e) {
 this.setState({ query: e.target.value });

  this.optionValue = e.target.value.length;
}

render() {
  const { query } = this.state;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {this.optionValue > 1 ? (
          <div className="loading" />
        ) : (
            <div className="not-loading" />
          )}
        <NewSearch query={query} updateQuery={this.updateQuery} />
      </div>
      <Debounce ms={1000}>
        <BusInfo query={query} />
      </Debounce>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Aron, this makes sense. I used the code provided and now I get :    Line 23:11:  'optionValue' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
  Line 31:10:  'optionValue' is not defined

Comment: Yeah that's because if you want to use `optionValue` in your render method you need to make it available to it, it can't just magically find it from inside another function. Put it on the component as `this.optionValue = e.target.value.length` and access it like `this.optionValue ? ... : ...`

Comment: Thank you Aron for your answers and help :)